# Win 10 pro VS code error

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble getting powershell to load in  vscode, i dont know what else to do. when i try to load powershell it fails every time with the below error about language service failing to start. i have searched far and wide and i cant find anything. None of my colleagues have seen this before, and i have another laptop ( win 7) and this is not an issue. The issue is on my Win 10 Pro core i7 laptop.  Anyone seen this before, know how to fix it?

Error

```
[19:59:40] Language server starting...

powershell.exe started --

pid: 8808

exe: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

args: C:\Users\Jones'\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.1\scripts\Start-EditorServices.ps1
      -EditorServicesVersion '1.4.1'
      -HostName 'Visual Studio Code Host'
      -HostProfileId 'Microsoft.VSCode'
      -HostVersion '1.4.1'
      -AdditionalModules @('PowerShellEditorServices.VSCode')
      -BundledModulesPath 'C:\Users\Jones'\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.1\modules' -EnableConsoleRepl -LogLevel 'Normal'
      -LogPath 'C:\Users\Jones'\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.1\logs\1503622780-5c7d3509-a90b-4797-841e-06b87d9b62ec1503622776726\EditorServices.log'
      -SessionDetailsPath 'C:\Users\Jones'\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.1\sessions\PSES-VSCode-6112-731972' -FeatureFlags @()

powershell.exe terminated or terminal UI was closed

[20:0:40] Language server startup failed.

The language service could not be started: 

Timed out waiting for session file to appear.
```

Comment: Is there any additional information in the log for the extension here: `C:\Users\Jones'\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.1\logs\1503622780-5c7d3509-a90b-4797-841e-06b87d9b62ec1503622776726\EditorServices.log`

Comment: You might try completely removing the extension and then install. I would ensure the the `.vscode\exentions\ms-vscode.powershell-1.4.1` directory is deleted.